# animation of an Actor in libgdx crashes on iphone

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, libgdx

I am using a class found here on stackover for the animation of the actors , but I crash on the physical device

class AnimatedImage.java:

```
public class AnimatedImage extends Image
{
    protected Animation animation = null;
    private float stateTime = 0;

    public AnimatedImage(Animation animation) {
        super(animation.getKeyFrame(0));
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta)
    {
        ((TextureRegionDrawable)getDrawable()).setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime+=delta, true));
        super.act(delta);
    }
}
```

create() method, get frames and add to the stage:

```
Array<TextureRegion> waveArrayTextureRegions = new Array<TextureRegion>();
for(int i = 1; i < 24; i++){
    waveArrayTextureRegions.add(new TextureRegion(new Texture("wave/4096/wave ("+i+").png")));
}
waveAnimation = new Animation(0.15f,waveArrayTextureRegions, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
waveActor = new AnimatedImage(waveAnimation );
waveActor.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 1.05f);
waveActor.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 1.05f);
waveActor.setPosition(0,0);
stage.addActor(waveActor);
```

I would add this class is animated actor , and , on Android no problem , but when I install it on my iPhone via RoboVM crashes .
It ' possible that the class or something wrong with liking to the iPhone ?
Additirruta on the iPhone simulator works only when I put it on the physical device I crashes in this class .
can someone give me a help?

Comment: Can you provide more info on the crash? A traceback and / or a log would be helpful.

Comment: Like user2016436 said we need more info.. Random guesses: the textures are to big or file system doesn't work the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that using texture over 4096px , instead , using images of not more than 4000 x 4000 px everything works beautifully . Evidently not supported larger resolutions .

In my case I had an image of 8000 px by 1200 , was used to make a scrolling background , the solution is to make two images from 4000 each and combine them with the code , perhaps in a Group ( libgdx ) .